# Use ElasticSearch to serve HTML pages

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm developing an application where users can create their own web pages. For this, they can create static HTML pages from their admin panel. Then this pages can be published on their web pages.

The fields of a page are: id, title, content, url.

The functionality is the next:

- Users has their own templates, this template includes a file called base.html where are the header, body, etc.. and all pages that they create inside the admin panel will be displayed inside this base.html file. So that "pages" they create in the backend only includes the content of the page, not the header, footer, etc..
- Also, the application allows users other functionality like a blog, and users can use some variables to display content inside their pages. Eg:

  {% for post in last_post %}

  #### {{ post.title }}

  {{ post.content|slice(0,255) }}

  {% endfor %}

Nowadays I'm saving this pages in MySQL and when a page is requested I search into MySql by the url field. The traffic has increased and I want to speed up the reads from the database and I have thought in use ElasticSearch for this.

My question is if could be a good idea, continue saving this HTML pages in MySQL and also in ElasticSearch. Then when a page is requested from the web page of the user make reads from ElasticSearch.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: How many pages a user may have ? Elasticsearch is more useful for searching and analytical things. What other options have you considered ? Have you tried using CDN ?

Comment: A user could have as many pages as he wants, also all pages of all users are saved in the same table (so i have a big table in mysql) This means when I search a page from one user, I have to filter by url and also by user_id. In addition to search by url also in admin panel, I search pages by id. Actually, i use a CDN to serve CSS files, images, etc.. could you explain to me how to serve this pages from CDN? i'm using twig as our template engine. thanks for your help!!

Comment: Did you think about creating a unique id using user name and url, may be some kind of hash value , and storing that content in cdn with that key ? Setting up a database just for serving static content seems overkill to me.

Comment: The application has other components like a blog, so we don't use only the database for this pages. This pages only includes the content, header, footer and other contents are not included in the content page. When a page is requested, the content of the page is displayed in a section of the template (template includes header, footer,...)

Comment: I see 2 problems using a CDN for this, 1º is that I need to search pages by url in the user webpage and by id under the admin panel, also under the backend user can filter their pages searching by name or date. So i need a database for this. 2º If I use CDN, first I need to search into MySQL then get_file_contents from CDN, i'm correct? Sorry i can`t write all in unqiue comment

Comment: It will be helpful if you can update your question with proper use cases and requirements. There might be other users reading your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143476/discussion-between-algoleigol-and-krrish).

Answer (score 1):

You can use elasticsearch - but just for a Key-Value lookup, it may be overkill - It makes more sense if your query is more than a key value lookup.

Have you considered using [redis](https://redis.io) to speedup things ?